# ExtJS grid as display only

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ext.grid.GridPanel is very cool grid, advanced with very powerfull features, sorting, resizeing, etc...

If I want to use it as nice looking output for my data (nice looking TABLE) there is pleny of unnessecery features, what I need to turn off, disable etc,

I wonder if is it a ExtJS class that look like a grid, got store inside - so can be loaded, updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a lot of performance problems with ExtJS Grid, so my solution was to switch to ListView. It is a lot simpler, doesn't have that many features, but still supports data stores.

Comment: ListView was removed in ExtJS4, so this answer does not apply for the more recent versions of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ext.extend` to create a GridPanel which has defaults exactly as you'd like them:

```
ConfiguredPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
  constructor: function(cfg) {
    cfg = Ext.applyIf(cfg || {}, {
      // defaults
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it a question was about something less than GridPanel, and extend is something OPOSITE ?

Comment: My read was it was asking how to make a class that disabled the various features of GridPanel that weren't wanted so there was less repetition in locking it down.

Answer (score 0):

The winner isssssssss...

**Ext.list.ListView !**